# eBPF: understand two macros in verifier code

Tags: c, linux-kernel, macros, bpf, ebpf

I'm looking in the `ebpf` verifier code, and I can't get my head around the following macros:

```
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER)  ((size_t)&((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)
#define offsetofend(TYPE, MEMBER) \
    (offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) + sizeof(((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER))

<...>

#define bpf_ctx_range(TYPE, MEMBER)                     \
    offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ... offsetofend(TYPE, MEMBER) - 1
#define bpf_ctx_range_till(TYPE, MEMBER1, MEMBER2)              \
    offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER1) ... offsetofend(TYPE, MEMBER2) - 1
```

I understand `offsetof` and `offsetofend` macros, but what is `...` meaning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out how it's used in `filter.c`:

```
    case bpf_ctx_range(struct __sk_buff, data):
```

This is GCC's **case range** extension (it's also supported by clang).  With it, a single case statement can match on a range of values, like `case 0 ... 5:`.  There's more information here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying.